# Could I make users config their PayPal account info in my website, so they can receive payments without giving me private info?

Tags: paypal

I'm building a web application and I would like that each user could configure their necessary information about their PayPal accounts in order to receive payments from the app. Can this be done?

I've seen a website that asks each user to type their *PayPal email* in order to receive payments, but I don't know what I have to do programmatically in order to use that user's account information so that person receives the payment.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: You can have a look at the API offered on the PayPal website, and see if one suits your needs: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this using PayPal Website Payments integration. Essentially your client needs to set their PayPal account up to receive payments, this usually requires them to prove that they're a legitimate business, although charities and some other personal reasons for taking payments such as wedding gifts are allowed as well.

Once setup they will be given a unique vendor id which can be embedded into a form on your website. When a customer wants to purchase something, this vendor id is passed to paypal and they handle the transaction from there. This means you don't have to store any credit card information on your website.

Check out the PayPal Website integration guide here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/pdf/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't see where to type the unique vendor id. Currently, I'm accepting payments to my account only with encrypted certs. And I need to tell PayPal the following:     
paypal_email: myemail@domain.com  
    paypal_secret: foobar  
    paypal_cert_id: DSGGUT3F4TTSW  
    paypal_url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: Having checked the documentation you're right, the unique vendor id is actually the vendor's email address. What's the problem with programmatically inserting this into a form in your web app? Like this: <input type="text" name="business" value="yourcustomer@name.com">